# TouchableOpacity takes more than half of width

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to arrange my cards into something like this
[image]

But heres what I got
[image]

As you can see the `TouchableOpacity` (yellow color) takes more than half of the container width (orange color).

I've tried may things by adding `width: "50%"` and set `alignItems` with `flex-start`, `flex-end`, etc but it only make things worse.

Here's my card component code

```
const SmallMateriCard = (props) => {

  return (
    <NativeBaseProvider >
      <Box maxW={"70%"} alignItems="flex-start" style={{backgroundColor:"blue"}}>
        {/* <Pressable onPress={props.onPress}> */}
        <Box
          borderRadius={18}
          overflow="hidden"
          style={{
            width: "100%",
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            shadowColor: '#000',
            shadowOffset: {
              width: 0,
              height: 0,
            },
            shadowOpacity: 0.1,
            shadowRadius: 3,
            elevation: 4,
          }}>
          <Box>
            <AspectRatio w="100%" ratio={6/5} >
              {props.cardIcon && (
                <Image
                  borderRadius={18}
                  source={{uri: props.cardIcon}}
                  alt="image"
                  
                />
              )}
            </AspectRatio>
          </Box>
          <Stack px="6" py="6" >
            <Text
              style={[
                font.family.extrabold,
                { fontSize: 15, color: color.primary },
              ]}>
              {props.title}
            </Text>
          </Stack>
        </Box>
        {/* </Pressable> */}
      </Box>
    </NativeBaseProvider>
  );
};

export default SmallMateriCard;
```

and here's my screen code

```
const UKKSekunderScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View
        style={[mixins.margin(16,16)]}>
        <ScrollView >
        <View style={[mixins.margin(16,16), layout.display.flex, layout.justify.between, { backgroundColor:"orange", flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap' }]}>
          {UKK_SEKUNDER.map((item, key) => (
            <TouchableOpacity key={key} style={{ backgroundColor:"yellow", }}>
              <View
                style={[layout.margin.vertical(10)]}
              >
                <SmallMateriCard {...item} />
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))}
        </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default UKKSekunderScreen;
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Gaurav's solution works but there's a new problem when I integrated it with my expandable component. The cards are overlaps when the component is collapsed.
[image]

**EDIT 2**

Solved by adding `overflow: 'hidden'`.

Comment: @GauravRoy here you go https://snack.expo.dev/@minumsusu/1b0ae9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey check this please https://snack.expo.dev/HUhqzIpYv

[image]

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your desired output would be a flex row with wrap enabled such as:

```
<View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-start', alignItems: 'center'}}>
 <View style={{
   justifyContent: 'flex-start', 
   alignItems: 'center', 
   flexDirection:'row', 
   flexWrap: 'wrap'
 }}>
  <Box style={{width: '50%'}} {...} />
  <Box style={{width: '50%'}} {...} />
  <Box style={{width: '50%'}} {...} />
  <Box style={{width: '50%'}} {...} />
  ....
 </View>
</View>
```

You could add some padding and margin to the box to add some space in-between them.

Edit: Here's an example with plain text, just to notice the layout:

```
 <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <View
        style={{
          justifyContent: 'flex-start',
          alignItems: 'center',
          flexDirection: 'row',
          flexWrap: 'wrap',
        }}>
        <Text
          style={{width: '40%', borderWidth: 2, padding: '10%', margin: '5%', textAlign: 'center'}}>
          Text
        </Text>
        <Text
          style={{width: '40%', borderWidth: 2, padding: '10%', margin: '5%', textAlign: 'center'}}>
          Text
        </Text>
        <Text
          style={{width: '40%', borderWidth: 2, padding: '10%', margin: '5%', textAlign: 'center'}}>
          Text
        </Text>
        <Text
          style={{width: '40%', borderWidth: 2, padding: '10%', margin: '5%', textAlign: 'center'}}>
          Text
        </Text>
        <Text
          style={{width: '40%', borderWidth: 2, padding: '10%', margin: '5%', textAlign: 'center'}}>
          Text
        </Text>
        <Text
          style={{width: '40%', borderWidth: 2, padding: '10%', margin: '5%', textAlign: 'center'}}>
          Text
        </Text>
        <Text
          style={{width: '40%', borderWidth: 2, padding: '10%', margin: '5%', textAlign: 'center'}}>
          Text
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
```